# Could hibernation kill my laptop battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, hibernate

My laptop is running Arch Linux and I purchased a battery late last year. However, over the last few weeks, my battery life has declined rapidly (from over 2 hours to less than 1 hour). Over the course of two weeks, the "capacity" (according to KDE) has gone from 99% to 43%.

During the time I owned the battery, I replaced my hard drive with a Samsung SSD and enabled the self-encryption feature. A byproduct of the SED is that the system has to go into hibernation instead of sleep when the lid is closed. As a student, I move my laptop around quite a bit, meaning that I tend to open and close my computer fairly frequently. **I am wondering if repeated hibernation could have damaged my battery or caused it to drain more quickly.**

At this point, the battery should not be going bad, as I bought it less than 6 months ago. I have tried to keep the battery as healthy as possible, as I unplug the computer overnight, and I avoid draining it to the point of shutdown.

Comment: The thing that kills it the fastes is when you use it and keep it plugged in into a power source even tough it is fully charged.

Comment: Yes, but I have my laptop plugged in *less* than average if anything, and I always unplug it at night. There are days where it is plugged in more often, but there are other laptops in my house that are plugged in far more frequently than mine and those batteries have not degraded anywhere near as rapidly.

Comment: Hibernation saving session to a file and turn computer completely off, so it won't drain your battery.

Comment: @RamonRobben Modern computer managing charging pretty well, If battery fully charged, internal unit will cut off battery from charging. Even more, nowadays systems analyzing charge/discharge pattern and if computer continuously plugged in  then charge unit wouldn't charge battery to 100% level leaving it in most optimized stage for long live by restricting charge level around 75%. Don't forget also that when you running on battery, computer power is less than it plugged(default). To manage long battery live, it better to train it every 3 months by doing complete discharge and charge again

Comment: Did you buy an original battery? It may have been a bad one to begin with.

Comment: @DanielB yes the battery is original. I ordered it directly from the manufacturer (Toshiba). I think it may be bad, but it seems like there would have been more problems initially.

Comment: Nothing will kill your battery. Hibernation will waste your SSD's TBW.

Answer (score 0):

There are more things to consider that could kill/drain your battery life. Its not only Hibernation mode that will decrease the life of your battery. Hibernation mode is infact better than sleep mode.

By buying yourself an SSD you have already increased the batterly-life on the storage part. Since it needs less power according to a question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Do-SSDs-use-more-or-less-power-than-HDDs-and-by-how-much).

> Simple mathematics shows that the SSD is still going to be more
>   power-efficient. Using my figures:
>
> 5V 500mA for, say, 45 mins in every hour of operation amounts to 112
>   Wh per hour (mechanical)
>
> 5v 1A for, say, 10 mins every hour amounts to 50Wh per hour (SSD).
>
> That means that, given the way I use my laptop, the SSD is saving me
>   better than 50% in power which has a notable effect on battery-life.

Because you might be interested in how to maximize battery life here are some tips.

---

**Use Hibernation instead of Sleep**

- Sleeping will use some power to keep the RAM running to get you back
  where you left off.
- Hibernation mode will save the system state to the SSD and turns
  itself off using almost no power at all.

**Use fewer Startup Programs and Lighter Software**

- Don't use a screensaver. They are pointless and drain your battery.
- Run fewer programs in the background.
- Use less resource intensive programs. Heavy programs tend to use more CPU causing it to drain battery power faster than a program that is very lightweight.
- Try to not maximize your ram usage to 100%. If your computer fills its RAM and needs more memory, it will move data to the page file on its hard drive, and this extra hard drive usage can drain battery.

**Things you can do in windows/linux**

- Use the power troubleshooting tool in Windows 7 and 8 which scans and
  fixes your computer from common battery drains
- For linux an application like TLP can boost your battery life.
- Turn on Power Saver in the windows Power Options
- Lower the screen brightness
- Disable Bluetooth and Other Hardware Devices that you don't use.
- Change your power plan options to turn off display after 5 minutes not used.

The usual tips for boosting battery life on a Windows laptop apply to Linux laptops, too.

[source](https://www.howtogeek.com/169720/how-to-increase-your-windows-laptops-battery-life/)

Comment: Did you even read his question? He said he's using an SSD and is running Linux, not Windows. Sheesh.

Comment: @HighTechGeek I forgot about the SSD replacement. Windows users might see this question aswell. Thats why I included that part. I have edited the title of the last part and added extra line so people know most of it can be done on windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if repeated hibernation could have damaged my battery
>   or caused it to drain more quickly

Hibernate is the same thing as being off!, **But** some laptops have some additional power options like turning ON the USB bus in hibernate "EuP".

For example Toshiba nb305 you can charge other things over USB even if you turn it off completely or put it in hibernation.

You can turn OFF this option from your BIOS if you have it!

> Over the course of two weeks, the "capacity" (according to KDE) has
>   gone from 99% to 43%.

Some laptops need battery reset "calibrate" from time to time, Read [this documentation](https://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/) about reset batteries.

There is an average lifespan for every battery maybe you hit the limit :) and need other battery, read your battery datasheet.

Heat will destroy your battery faster, some cheap batteries don't have heat sensors inside them at all, maybe that the cause! maybe the IC just fail!
[image]

Comment: I do have a Toshiba laptop, but I've gone through BIOS before and I'm pretty sure it doesn't have EuP. I also don't generally leave USB devices plugged in.